# Select memebers of master-detail relationships in Map using a single query

Tags: soql

Is it possible to select memebers of master-detail relationships in Map using a single query?

In other words is it possible to write something like the following?

```
Map<Id, List<SObject>> masterToDetails = [
  SELECT Id (SELECT Name, Foo FROM Details__r)
  FROM Master__c
];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, here is the way

```
Map<Id, Account> masterToDetails = new  Map<Id, Account>([
  SELECT Id, (SELECT Name, Foo FROM Details__r)
  FROM Acccount
]);

for(Account a:masterToDetails.values()){
    //do something
    System.debug(a.Details__r);
}
```

Refer [Maps of sObjects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_map_sobject.htm)